# How to install yagiuda-1.19?

Tags: software-installation, icons

I got the following results when trying to install yagiuda using  `sudo apt-get install yagiuda`  but yagiuda is not creating any icon through which I can use it.

```
sudo apt-get install yagiuda
[sudo] password for atharv: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libenet7 libfluidsynth1 libllvm3.8
  libmikmod3 libmircommon5 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libsdl-mixer1.2 libsnapd-glib1 libxcb-composite0
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-93 linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic musescore-soundfont-gm
  redeclipse-common redeclipse-data snapd-login-service
  timgm6mb-soundfont ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yagiuda
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 288 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 yagiuda amd64 1.19-9 [80.6 kB]
Fetched 80.6 kB in 6s (13.4 kB/s)                           
Selecting previously unselected package yagiuda.
(Reading database ... 278666 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../yagiuda_1.19-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking yagiuda (1.19-9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up yagiuda (1.19-9) ...
```

Comment: and? what's wrong?

Comment: it's not creating any icon through which I can use it

Answer (score 1):

The programs that are installed by the yagiuda package are terminal programs so there isn't any yagiuda icon because they are run from the terminal. The following programs are run from a terminal: **dipole first input mutual optimise output randtest selftest yagi**.

For example the  program  yagi is one of a number of executable programs that forms part of a set of programs, collectively known as the Yagi-Uda project. For information about the usage of yagi run the following command which shows yagi's manual page:

```
man yagi
```